# C# MDI child not showing

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I am using a method sice I will have alot of child forms. Now it does show when I call a form by clicking on a button, but not after the login child is closed.

Method:

```
private void mForms(Form f)
{
    if (this.MdiChildren.Contains(f)) 
    {
        f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
    else
    {
        f.MdiParent = this; f.Show();
    }
}
```

This just simply checks if the MDIcontainer already contains the requested form. If yes, put it back up again (in case it's minimized), if not, show it.

Now I can call the forms using this:

```
private void ts_bestand_studenten_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (add_student.IsDisposed)
    {
        add_student = new add_student();
    }

    mForms(add_student); 
}
```

This checks if it is disposed already or not. If so, redefine it. Then it calls to the method to open the right form. This works as it should.

Now the problematic part:
After the login screen is closed and user is logged in, the userlevel is defined. I should be able to open another form. This is the method I use for that: (NOTE: the userlevels work fine since it does reach the Messagebox)

```
// Predefines start_screen_admin
Form start_screen_admin = new start_screen_admin();

public void mCommitRights()
{
    if (userlevel.gCheckLevel == 0)
    {
        // Admin, no changes
        MessageBox.Show("Admin");
        mForms(start_screen_admin);
    }
    ... more of the same to check for userlevels
}
```

Now you think this should work. I don't have to redefine it because it's the first time it opens and it is already predefined. The MessageBox shows, but the form does not. I really can't see a problem in this. I tried everything I could think of..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include the `Select()` method to bring the form to the front:

Try changing it to this:

```
private void mForms(Form f) {
  if (this.MdiChildren.Contains(f)) {
    f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    f.Select();
  } else {
    f.MdiParent = this;
    f.Show();
  }
}
```

Comment: No difference. Like I have stated in my post: The method to call the forms works perfectly with other forms. When I call it when the login is closed, it doesn't show, not even minimized.

Comment: @Rune I can't reproduce it.  You aren't showing the code where you create `start_screen_admin`-- maybe the problem is there.  Also, try to avoid debugging with MessageBoxes-- it can interfere with the GUI.

Comment: @Lars_Tech I added it to the post. I use this: 
Form start_screen_admin = new start_screen_admin();

Comment: @Rune Can you show start_screen_admin without the mForms method?  If the problem only happens on that form, then check the properties, constructor method, and any events on that form that might be interfering.  I can't find anything wrong with the posted code.

Comment: @Lars_Tech I went through the Designer part of the form > nothing. It can show as a normal form or dialog though, but as normal form, it immediately jumps behind the MDI container. I think that might be the problem, but I don't know why.